# Nginx Reverse Proxy Subdomain Not Working

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 NodeJS Apps running on `http://localhost:3000` and `http://localhost:3001`. I am trying to get both running using Nginx reverse proxy at `http://test.com` and `http://api.test.com` respectively.

My Nginx version is nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

File: sites-enabled/api.test.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name api.test.com;

    root /var/www/html/api;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /app_api_location {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

File: sites-enabled/test.com

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    root /var/www/html/test;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Neither of the apps is working. There are no other files in sites-enabled. It is a new server setup with Ubuntu 22.04. I have done this a few times before and matched it to other reverse proxies running on my other servers, I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: what do you mean "not working"? any errors? any logs?

Comment: Maybe your apps are not currently running, or maybe nginX resolves `localhost` to `:::1` rather than `127.0.0.1` or maybe your firewall is rejecting external connections to port 80, or who knows what else might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved. Whenever using services like DigitalOcean or AWS Lightsail. UFW is entirely disabled and the control panels give access to manage(allow and disallow traffic). It was immediately resolved when I allowed port 80 HTTP traffic from the dashboard. Silly mistake.